# Display result of Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, toad

I creates a procedure using Toad Client that is

```
create or replace procedure getuid(eid_pro varchar2)is 
l_value number;
begin
select  uniqueid 
into l_value 
from enrollment 
where eid=eid_pro;
end ;
```

When I execute it by Followings

```
begin
getuid('245698154');
end;
```

It executed successfully but result is not displayed in data grid.
Please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Turn the procedure into a function.

```
create or replace function getuid(eid_pro varchar2) return number is
   l_value number;
begin
   select uniqueid
     into l_value
     from enrollment
    where eid = eid_pro;

   return l_value;
end;
```

And then select the function.

```
select getuid('245698154') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case please use a function and then you can use it in a select statement which can show the result in the grid.

```
create or replace function getuid(eid_pro varchar2) return number is 
l_value number;
begin
select  uniqueid 
into l_value 
from enrollment 
where eid=eid_pro;
return l_value;
end ;


select getuid('245698154') from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks.. but it displays result on DBMS output and I want on Data Grid..plz help

Comment: please see the changes, use a function like i have changed in my answer above.

Comment: You have declared `eid_pro varchar2` so it is a string, but you are passing a number to the function...